# c++ map find() to possibly insert(): how to optimize operations?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I'm using the STL map data structure, and at the moment my code first invokes **find()**: if the key was not previously in the map, it calls **insert()** it, otherwise it does nothing.

```
map<Foo*, string>::iterator it;
it = my_map.find(foo_obj);   // 1st lookup

if(it == my_map.end()){
  my_map[foo_obj] = "some value";  // 2nd lookup
}else{
  // ok do nothing.
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way than this, because as far as I can tell, in this case when I want to insert a key that is not present yet, I perform 2 lookups in the map data structures: one for **find()**, one in the **insert()**  (which corresponds to the *operator[]* ).

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Normally if you do a find and maybe an insert, then you want to keep (and retrieve) the old value if it already existed.  If you just want to overwrite any old value, `map[foo_obj]="some value"` will do that.

Here's how you get the old value, or insert a new one if it didn't exist, with one map lookup:

```
typedef std::map<Foo*,std::string> M;
typedef M::iterator I;
std::pair<I,bool> const& r=my_map.insert(M::value_type(foo_obj,"some value"));
if (r.second) { 
    // value was inserted; now my_map[foo_obj]="some value"
} else {
    // value wasn't inserted because my_map[foo_obj] already existed.
    // note: the old value is available through r.first->second
    // and may not be "some value"
}
// in any case, r.first->second holds the current value of my_map[foo_obj]
```

This is a common enough idiom that you may want to use a helper function:

```
template <class M,class Key>
typename M::mapped_type &
get_else_update(M &m,Key const& k,typename M::mapped_type const& v) {
    return m.insert(typename M::value_type(k,v)).first->second;
}

get_else_update(my_map,foo_obj,"some value");
```

If you have an expensive computation for v you want to skip if it already exists (e.g. memoization), you can generalize that too:

```
template <class M,class Key,class F>
typename M::mapped_type &
get_else_compute(M &m,Key const& k,F f) {
   typedef typename M::mapped_type V;
   std::pair<typename M::iterator,bool> r=m.insert(typename M::value_type(k,V()));
   V &v=r.first->second;
   if (r.second)
      f(v);
   return v;
}
```

where e.g.

```
struct F {
  void operator()(std::string &val) const 
  { val=std::string("some value")+" that is expensive to compute"; }
};
get_else_compute(my_map,foo_obj,F());
```

If the mapped type isn't default constructible, then make F provide a default value, or add another argument to get_else_compute.

Comment: ok, so this is indeed the only way to do it, the previous comment on the operator[] was wrong (it overwrites the previous key/value pair if the key was already in the map)

Answer (score 13):

There are two main approaches. The first is to use the insert function that takes a value type and which returns an iterator and a bool which indicate if an insertion took place and returns an iterator to either the existing element with the same key or the newly inserted element.

```
map<Foo*, string>::iterator it;
it = my_map.find(foo_obj);   // 1st lookup

my_map.insert( map<Foo*, string>::value_type(foo_obj, "some_value") );
```

The advantage of this is that it is simple. The major disadvantage is that you always construct a new value for the second parameter whether or not an insertion is required. In the case of a string this probably doesn't matter. If your value is expensive to construct this may be more wasteful than necessary.

A way round this is to use the 'hint' version of insert.

```
std::pair< map<foo*, string>::iterator, map<foo*, string>::iterator >
    range = my_map.equal_range(foo_obj);

if (range.first == range.second)
{
    if (range.first != my_map.begin())
        --range.first;

    my_map.insert(range.first, map<Foo*, string>::value_type(foo_obj, "some_value") );
}
```

The insertiong is guaranteed to be in amortized constant time only if the element is inserted immediately after the supplied iterator, hence the `--`, if possible.

**Edit**

If this need to `--` seems odd, then it is. There is an open defect (233) in the standard that hightlights this issue although the description of the issue as it applies to `map` is clearer in the duplicate issue [246](http://anubis.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#246).

Comment: The "hint" version isn't available for hash_map, but for map that's probably simpler than defining a lambda for my get_else_compute, where I default construct then modifying the returned iterator's value (you can do that inline without a lambda of course).

Comment: By hash_map, I guess I mean std::unordered_map in tr1 or C++0x.

Comment: True, it also bugs me that the hint isn't guaranteed to be amortized constant time if the insertion happens immediately before the hint as this would work at the beginning and then end of the container.

Comment: Dinkumware std::map ensures "Insertion can occur in amortized constant time, instead of logarithmic time, if the insertion point immediately precedes or follows where."

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you want to insert when it's not found. If default construction and setting the value after that is not expensive, I'd suggest simpler version with 1 lookup:

```
string& r = my_map[foo_obj];    // only lookup & insert if not existed
if (r == "") r = "some value";  // if default (obj wasn't in map), set value
                                // else existed already, do nothing
```

If your example tells what you actually want, consider adding that value as `str Foo::s` instead, you already have the object, so no lookups would be needed, just check if it has default value for that member. And keep the objs in the `std::set`. Even extending `class FooWithValue2` may be cheaper than using `map`.

But If joining data through the map like this is really needed or if you want to update only if it existed, then Jonathan has the answer.