# How should std::map be used with a value that does not have a default constructor?

Tags: c++

I've got a value type that I want put into a map.
It has a nice default copy constructor, but does not have a default constructor.

I believe that so long as I stay away from using `operator[]` that everything will be OK.

However I end up with pretty ugly constructs like this to actually insert an object.
(I think insert just fails if there is already a value for that key).

```
// equivalent to m[5]=x but without default construction

std::map<int,X>::iterator it = m.find(5);
if( it != m.end() )
{
   m->second = x;
}
else
{
  m->insert( std::make_pair(5,x) );
}
```

Which I believe will scan the map twice, and also looks pretty ugly.

Is there a neater / more efficient way to do this?

Comment: existing answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409454/c-map-find-to-possibly-insert-how-to-optimize-operations

Comment: @miaout17, yep that existing answer will solve it. However the question that is solves is a different issue IMO.

Comment: @miaout17, actually that doesn't quite solve it. That is the case where you don't store a new value into the map if one already exists. But dont over write it with a new value. The functions ned to be tweaked slightly to do that ... Someone posted a solution that did that correctly and then deleted their answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply "insert-or-overwrite" with the standard `insert` function:

```
auto p = mymap.insert(std::make_pair(key, new_value));

if (!p.second) p.first->second = new_value;  // overwrite value if key already exists
```

If you want to pass the elements by rerference, make the pair explicit:

```
insert(std::pair<K&, V&>(key, value));
```

If you have a typedef for the map like `map_t`, you can say `std::pair<map_t::key_type &, map_t::mapped_type &>`, or any suitable variation on this theme.

---

Maybe this is best wrapped up into a helper:

```
template <typename Map>
void insert_forcefully(Map & m,
                       typename Map::key_type const & key,
                       typename Map::mapped_type const & value)
{
  std::pair<typename Map::iterator, bool> p = m.insert(std::pair<typename Map::key_type const &, typename Map::mapped_type const &>(key, value));
  if (!p.second) { p.first->second = value; }
}
```

Comment: The only issue I have with this is that constructing a pair from `key` or `new_value` may be expensive, or in the case of C++11 impossible (`new_value` could be move-only). I've ran into this issue in my code. :(

Comment: @GMan: Why not use a pair of references? Actually, does `make_pair` deduce a reference type? Otherwise use `std::tie`.

Comment: Both of those won't work because `insert` requires a `pair_type`. It's really just a short-coming of the container.

Comment: @GMan: Yes, true, `tie` makes tuples, not `pairs`. Meh, you can make the pair-of-references explicit; I added that.

Comment: Wouldn't it still copy, since the `insert()` itself takes a reference to `map::value_type`, which is a `pair<const K, V>` and not a pair of references?

Comment: @DaveS: I think it's fine. It doesn't make any more copies than necessary.

Comment: @KerrekSB Is'n't there should be: if (!p.second) p->second = new_value;  // overwrite value if key already exists ?

Answer (score 2):

You could first get the position to insert the pair with `lower_bound`, then check if it's already there, and if not, insert it, providing the iterator where to insert. Something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you missed in the interface of `map` (and the like):

- `insert(value_type)` returns a `std::pair<iterator, bool>`, the `.first` member points to the element with the key you tried to insert and the `.second` member indicates whether it is actually the element you tried to insert or another that previously was in the container.
- `insert(iterator, value_type)` allows you to give a hint as to where insert

The latter is not necessarily useful in your situation though.

```
typedef std::map<int,X> Map;

// insert and check
std::pair<Map::iterator, bool> const result =
  map.insert(std::make_pair(5, x));            // O(log N)

if (not result.second)
{
  result->first.second = x;                    // O(1)
  // OR
  using std::swap;
  swap(result->first.second, x);
}
```

If you type does not support assignment and there is no swap, however, you need to bite the bullet:

```
// locate and insert
Map::iterator position = map.lower_bound(5);         // O(log N)
if (position != map.end() and position->first == 5) 
{
  position = map.erase(position);                    // O(1)
}
map.insert(position, std::make_pair(5, x));          // O(log N) if rebalancing
```

In C++11, the `insert` methods are doubled:

- `insert(value_type const&)` // insertion by copy
- `insert(P&&)` // insertion by move

and with perfect forwarding we get the new `emplace` method. Similar to insert, but which construct the element in place by forwarding the arguments to its constructor. How it differentiate arguments for the key and value is a mystery to me though.