# Get or set element in a Javascript ES6 Map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, find, addition

Is it possible to find or add an element in one step in a Javascript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Map/has)?

I would like to do the following in one step (to avoid looking twice for the right place of the key):

```
// get the value if the key exists, set a default value otherwise
let aValue = aMap.get(aKey)
if(aValue == null) {
    aMap.set(aKey, aDefaultValue)
}
```

Instead I would like to search for the key only once.

In c++, one can use [std::map::insert()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409465/719276) or [std::map::lower_bound()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101980/719276)

In javascript the code could look like this:

```
let iterator = aMap.getPosition(aKey)
let aValue = aMap.getValue(iterator)
if(aValue == null)
{
    aMap.setWithHint(aKey, aValue, iterator)
}
```

or

```
let aValue = aMap.getOrSet(aKey, aDefaultValue)
```

I suppose that it is not possible, but I want to make sure I am correct. Also I am interested in knowing why it is not possible while it is an important feature.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you are concerned about `aKey` having to be looked up twice in your code example?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem.

Comment: In general, you don't have to worry about these kind of micro-optimizations in JavaScript. Modern JavaScript engines do a pretty good job at handling those. Also, as far as I know, there is no way to prevent this using maps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lookup has to happen anyway, it doesn't matter much if you avoid it, at least until the engines are optimized much more.

But `Map.has` is a nicer solution and should be a bit faster than `Map.get()`. For example:

`myMap.has(myKey) ? true : myMap.set(myKey, myValue)`

Performance should be irrelevant on this level unless you're google-scale. But if it's a serious bottleneck, an Array should still be faster than Map/Set for the forseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

I personally ended up changing my Map to a simple Object. That allows to write a reduce (that groups entries into a Map of Sets) like this:

```
.reduce((a, [k, v]) => (a[k] = a[k] || new Set()).add(v) ? a : a, {})
```

With Map it should have become

```
.reduce((a, [k, v]) => (a.has(k) ? a : a.set(k, new Set())).get(k).add(v) ? a : a, new Map())
```

That feels little too cumbersome for this purpose.

I agree that something like this would be ideal if ever supported:

```
.reduce((a, [k, v]) => a.getOrSet(k, new Set()).add(v) ? a : a, new Map())
```